# Compiling 32 bits driver using MSVC 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, wdk

The project I am working on needs to compile 32bits, 64bits, and ARM64 drivers. I am shifting the build environment from VS2019 and VS2022. For Driver Compilation I am using the newer WDK (version 22H2 WDK). Now the problem is that newer WDK doesn't support 32 bits driver compilation. I am thinking of using olde WDK (version 21H2 WDK) but it is not supported by VS2022. What can be done in this case. Is there any possibility I can copile 32 bits driver using VS2022 (maybe using older WDK).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk :
Visual Studio 2022 is not supported by the Windows 11, version 21H2 WDK. To use Visual Studio 2022 to develop and test drivers, download the Windows 11, version 22H2 WDK. For details, see Download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 11 does not have a 32-bit version, thus the WDK for Win11 doesn't support 32-bit, i thought. However, I can't understand that the newer (22H2) WDK can still compiling code targeting an older Windows (lowest to Windows 10) with 32-bit support, but it can't produce a 32-bit things for the older Windows.

We can use an older EWDK version to build 32-bit driver. The latest EWDK that works is [EWDK for Windows Server 2022 with Visual Studio Build Tools 16.9.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/hardware/enterprise-wdk-license-2019).

In theory, developing with latest VS/WDK, and building with EWDK, is just fine. The drawback is we need to keep our code base compatitable with the older WDK. But if the two version diffs so much, the newer WDK may refuse to work with the deprecated/abandanded API, this sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a hack which allows to build 32 bit drivers using this WDK.
One need edit file:  "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\10.0.22621.0\WindowsDriver.Common.targets**"

Find there a string:  "**Error out if Arch x86 or ARM is used with KM drivers**"
You'll see the following:

> ```
> <Error Text=" '$(Platform)' is not a valid architecture for Kernel mode drivers or UMDF drivers"
>        Condition="'$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)' &gt; '$(TargetPlatformVersion_CO)' and ('$(DDKPlatform)' == 'x86' or '$(DDKPlatform)' == 'ARM') and ('$(PlatformToolset)' == 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0' or '$(DriverType)' == 'UMDF') " />
> ```

Replace 'x86' by 'xx86'

And you'll be able to build 32 bit drivers